# Trouble deserializing Json from REST service

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, deserialization

I'm having the hardest time deserializing a json string.

I was using the RestSharp api which worked great if I specified the RootElement on the request. I then moved to Hammock for the OAuth functionality, but the deserialization isn't working so easily.

I've tried using DataContractJsonSerializer

> DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List));
>     var member = (List)ser.ReadObject(response.ContentStream);

but this gives me an InvalidCastException.

I tried JsonConvert

```
var members = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Member>>(response.Content);
```

but I get the exception: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Member]'.

RestSharp took care of this easily when calling ExecuteAsync.  `Client.ExecuteAsync<List<Member>>(request, (response) =>`

I'm at my wits end. *Maybe I need a Hammock equivalent to RestSharp's RootElement property??*  Is it just that my Json is difficult to convert?

Here is my Member object

```
public partial class Member 
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Joined { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Visited { get; set; }
    public string Photo_url { get; set; }
    public string lon { get; set; }
}
```

here is the Json:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "zip": "11111",
            "lon": "-122.22000122070312",
            "photo_url": "http: //photos1.aaaaa.com/photos/member/1/6/c/e/member_4469838.jpeg",
            "link": "http: //www.aaaa.com/members/7804365",
            "state": "AA",
            "lang": "en_US",
            "city": "MyCity",
            "country": "us",
            "id": "7804365",
            "visited": "Sat Feb 19 02: 36: 40 EST 2011",
            "topics": [
                {
                    "id": 3340,
                    "urlkey": "pickupsoccer",
                    "name": "Pick-up Soccer"
                },
                {
                    "id": 468,
                    "urlkey": "dads",
                    "name": "Dads"
                },
                {
                    "id": 20557,
                    "urlkey": "coed-soccer",
                    "name": "Coed Soccer"
                },
                {
                    "id": 148421,
                    "urlkey": "windowsphone",
                    "name": "Windows Phone"
                }
            ],
            "joined": "Thu Aug 07 15: 32: 06 EDT 2008",
            "bio": "",
            "name": "aaa bbbb",
            "other_services": {
                "linkedin": {
                    "identifier": "http: //www.bbb.com/in/zzzzz"
                }
            },
            "lat": "47.790000915527344"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "lon": "",
        "count": 1,
        "link": "https: //api.aaaaa.com/members",
        "next": "",
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "https: //api.aaaaa.com/members?relation=self&order=name&offset=0&format=json&page=800",
        "id": "",
        "title": "Members",
        "updated": "Fri Sep 10 13: 08: 07 EDT 2010",
        "description": "API method",
        "method": "Members",
        "lat": ""
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Adding a wrapper object for my Member class that encapsulates the entire json result fixed this.

```
public partial class Members
{
    public List<Member> results { get; set; }
    public object meta { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can can deserialize using the following:

```
var members = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Members>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Can you show us the JSON data without all the escaped double quotes? The transmitted JSON data hopefully doesn't contain them since they're not valid JSON data but probably an artifact of your C# development environment.

Comment: removed the escape chars and formatted. Solution found. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are about three problem areas in your JSON data:

1. The way it is presented here, it contains a lot of backslashes and double quotes at the beginnging and end that don't work in JSON. It's difficult to tell from your question whether this is an artifact of copying it from the VisualStudio debugger or is really a problem in the data.
2. The transmitted data is not a list of *Member* instance but rather an object containing both a list of member instances and some additional meta information. So you need to introduce an additional class with a the two members *results* and *meta*.
3. Your class *Member* uses properties starting with an uppercase letter while the JSON data uses all lowercase letters. You can either change the property names or uses data *DataMember* annoation:

So the solution could be:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonResponse));
JsonResponse jsonResponse = (JsonResponse)ser.ReadObject(response.ContentStream);
```

with the following class definitions:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Member 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "joined")]
    public string Joined { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "zip")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "bio")]
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "state")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "city")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "visited")]
    public string Visited { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "photo_url")]
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lon")]
    public string Lon { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Meta
{
    [DataMember(Name = "lon")]
    public string Lon { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "next")]
    public string Next { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "total_count")]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class JsonResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public List<Member> Results { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "meta")]
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1 & 3 were pretty irrelevant, but #2 was right on the money! I was able to get around this in RestSharp by specifying the RootElement (so only the results were deserialized), but didn't think about changing the destination type to include results and meta. I was able to add a wrapper class (3 lines of code) to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In our project we r using Hammok for this, you can try to modify your class like this:

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Member 
{
   [DataMember(Name="zip")]
   public string Zip { get; set; }
   [DataMember(Name="photo_url")]
   public string Photo_url { get; set; }
   //Etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks, solution found, but this will be helpful in cleaning up my class when I get to that point. I don't like some of the member names the api uses.

Answer (score 0):

try using Json.net.
i found DataContractJsonSerializer too fetureless.
json.net provides great functionality.
it can be found at this link

http://json.codeplex.com/

it contains the .dll files and documentatio as well.
for web Documentation
 http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/